# Градиент сложной формы

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

WPF позволяет делать два вида градиентов: либо вдоль прямой линии от одной стороны фигуры к другой, либо круговой. А что делать, если мне нужен более сложный градиент? Например, я хочу цветом мягко выделить две диагонали? Или вообще нарисовать кривую линию с размытыми границами?

Comment: Написать своего наследника GradientBrush?

Comment: Так же есть эффекты: https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/graphics_and_animation/level14/14_3.php в т.ч можно использовать шейдеры

Comment: И как своего наследника GradientBrush подпихнуть в стандартный конвертер кистей?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: А там кисти не через TypeConverter создаются в XAML?

Comment: Ну если вы имеете ввиду короткий синтаксис, вроде `BorderBrush="Red"`, то да, строка преобразуется в SolidColorBrush с помощью TypeConverter (если точнее, с помощью [BrushConverter](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.brushconverter)). При желании можно написать свои конвертеры и добавить их, когда-то я такое делал. Но, скорее всего, смысла в этом с кастомной костью нет, проще использовать расширенный синтаксис (`<Border.BorderBrush><z:MyBrush ...>...</z:MyBrush></Border.BorderBrush>`) и создавать кисть в Xaml явно, потому что конвертер будет лишним переусложнением